# run named .exe in subdirectory in windows cmd

Tags: cmd

I feel stupid for asking this, but here goes. In linux/mac, you can run an executable file in the shell, simply by writing its name. Can you do something similar in windows command line?

Example: I am in directory `dir`. I want to run a file `a.exe` in `dir/subdir` without changing directory to `subdir`, or writing `subdir/a.exe`. Is this possible?

Comment: "a.exe was not recognized as an intern or extern command, a program or a batchfile".

Comment: i do have the file. just went to the directory and tried it. works fine. back in the superdirectory it doesn't work. you are right about the frontslash/backslash, but I don't believe it changes anything?

Comment: It would cause errors many places but i can navigate fine with it. "cd dir/subdir" and "cd dir\subdir" gets me the same place.

Comment: But i presume you can execute files from a higher dir in your cmd?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It *is* possible. All you need to do is ensure that the directory in which `a.exe` resides is included on the `path`.

Comment: I'll try to add it to the path then :) thank you

Comment: Works fine. Found out how to add it to the path here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows.

Comment: Hmm. I'd have googled "Path Editor" myself. All clicky and gooey.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to point out to the anonymous downvoters who haven't had the courtesy to explain their downvotes or offer another solution that OP was under the impression that the path separator in WIndows is `/` as it is in Linux AND that OP specifically asks "**without** changing directory to subdir, or  **writing subdir/a.exe**". AFAIAA, this is thus the *only* solution (without creating and executing a "shortcut")

Comment: Here 5 years later, I would just like to say that Magoo is correct. At the time, I didn't know that path was a thing, and it was indeed what I was looking for. So the downvotes are wrong.

Answer (score 32):

You can using one of the following:

- `"subdir/a.exe"`
- `subdir\a.exe`

Comment: OP specifically asks "without changing directory to subdir, or writing subdir/a.exe" and was under the impression that `/` is the Windows path-separator.

Answer (score 2):

You mean you don't want the double-quotes of `"subdir/a.exe"`? Anyway, if you change to a backslash, it does work; i.e.

`subdir\a.exe`